# How to unit tests a method that only does a foreach

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a simple method in my class that puts an element in the cache:

```
public void Put(TItem item)
{
  // Do something
}
```

Now I have added another method to be able to put multiple elements at once:

```
public void Put(IEnumerable<TItem> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Put(item);
    }
}
```

It seems that to avoid duplication I should only check that I call Put a number of times. But I can do this only indirectly as this is not a dependency. Is there a way to avoid copy/paste when testing these kind of methods? I can do a smoke test to check some outcomes of the Put, but it has a lot of unit tests on its own and they won't be complete in this case. Is there any good way out of the situation?

Comment: Can you not mock the item that contains the `Put` method? Then you could assert a method call count for a given `items` argument. Although personally I probably wouldn't bother with this one and instead just test `Put` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do tests on various conditions, but only with minimal validation of the results of `Put` itself - I assume there's some *fairly* simple way of checking whether or not an item has been put?

Possible tests:

- Null argument
- Empty collection
- Collection with one entry (sanity)
- Collection with two entries (sanity)
- Collection with repeated entries (x, y, x)
- Collection where putting an early entry causes an exception, if that's feasible

Now admittedly that may be seen as overkill for a simple `foreach` loop. I like the mantra of "test until fear turns to boredom."

Comment: Put has many different outcomes such as calling some methods on dependencies and so on. But there is a simple way to check if the item is inside or not, though in theory this method can put an item inside and fail to do other stuff. Do I understand you right that you suggest what I described as smoke tests: don't tests all of the outcomes but test IEnumerable specifics with only some simple ways of checking what Put should do ignoring complex cases like calling dependencies?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Absolutely. There's no point in retesting the functionality of `Put` - you're only interested in how your method interacts with `Put`. (For example, you *could* make your method continue calling `Put` after an error... possibly aggregating exceptions. Presumably you don't do that at the moment, but you *may* want a test to demonstrate that.)

Comment: Then if one someone day decides to refactor the method and not to call Put inside - some errors can be introduced (of course if we assume that someone doesn't fix the unit tests because he did not change the behaviour) and unit tests won't show them. But this is kind of a trade off not to duplicate tests.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: No, if they change the method not to call `Put` then your smoke tests would fail, because the behaviour *has* changed.

Comment: I mean if the change it in the way that will follow the basic functionality so that smoke tests won't break but some intricate behaviour that Put did before will be broken that is not covered by smoke tests.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: That would be a change to the (singular) `Put` method itself though, wouldn't it? In which case it should be covered by *those* unit tests (which should be much more exhaustive).

Comment: Well I meant that someone will not call a Put inside but will kind of duplicate the logic in Put but fail to duplicate it correctly. I guess that anyone who does this kind of things should just check the unit tests to avoid problems.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: That sounds like a pretty obscure possibility, to be honest... and anyone who starts moving *towards* code duplication without looking at the tests is already asking for trouble.

Comment: OK, thank you for help! I think I will do these smoke tests to check only the IEnumberable behaviour.

Comment: I have searched a little bit more and found suggestions (by MarkSeeman) to make basic Put virtual and test using dynamic mock or own subclass. Do you think this will be a better way to chose instead of smoke tests?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: Personally I don't. I'm a big fan of restricting inheritance - and I really don't like partial mocks for this sort of situation. But it's very much a matter of personal taste :)